# Erlang cowboy reply json data , float number precision is wrong?

Tags: json, erlang, cowboy, rfc4627

code is here :

```
RstJson = rfc4627:encode({obj, [{"age", 45.99}]}),
{ok, Req3} = cowboy_req:reply(200, [{<<"Content-Type">>, <<"application/json;charset=UTF-8">>}], RstJson, Req2)
```

then I get this wrong data from front client:

```
{
  "age": 45.990000000000002
}
```

the float number precision is changed !
how can I solved this problem?

Comment: Could you post the code on the client that receives that data? I would adventure it is something to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at the JSON that `rfc4627` generates:

```
> io:format("~s~n", [rfc4627:encode({obj, [{"age", 45.99}]})]).
{"age":4.59900000000000019895e+01}
```

It turns out that `rfc4627` encodes floating-point values by calling [`float_to_list/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#float_to_list-1), which uses "scientific" notation with 20 digits of precision.  [As Per Hedeland noted on the erlang-questions mailing list in November 2007](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-November/030955.html), that's an odd choice:

> A reasonable question could be why float_to_list/1 generates 20 digits
>   when a 64-bit float (a.k.a. C double), which is what is used internally,
>   only can hold 15-16 worth of them - I don't know off-hand what a 128-bit
>   float would have, but presumably significantly more than 20, so it's not
>   that either. I guess way back in the dark ages, someone thought that 20
>   was a nice and even number (I hope it wasn't me:-). The 6.30000 form is
>   of course just the ~p/~w formatting.

---

However, it turns out this is actually not the problem! In fact, `45.990000000000002` is equal to `45.99`, so you *do* get the correct value in the front end:

```
> 45.990000000000002 =:= 45.99.
true
```

As noted above, a 64-bit float can hold 15 or 16 significant digits, but `45.990000000000002` contains 17 digits (count them!).  It looks like your front end tries to print the number with more precision than it actually contains, thereby making the number *look* different even though it is in fact the same number.

---

The answers to the question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/113848) go into much more detail about why this actually makes sense, given how computers handle floating point values.

Answer (score 0):

the encode float number function in rfc4627 is :

```
encode_number(Num, Acc) when is_float(Num) ->
  lists:reverse(float_to_list(Num), Acc).
```

I changed it like this :

```
encode_number(Num, Acc) when is_float(Num) ->
  lists:reverse(io_lib:format("~p",[Num]), Acc).
```

Problem Solved.